# How to set end time to give me correct intervals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timepicker

I'm trying to fix my JQuery timepicker to give me correct end time. My current code works fine just when I pick start time and interval. Example: If I pick 8:00am and pick interval 30min my end time automatically will be 8:30am, but here my problem comes because I want after that when I click on my drop down End Time to see intervals like 8:30am(that I have), 9:00am, 9:30am, ... and so on until 5:00pm that is my last time. Here is my HTML code:

```js
 $(function() {
   for (var i = 5; i <= 60; i += 5) {
     $('#meeting').append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '   min' + '</option>');
   }

   function setEndTime() {
     var meetingLength = parseInt($('#meeting').find('option:selected').val() || 0);
     var selectedTime = $('#stime').timepicker('getTime');
     if (selectedTime == null || selectedTime == "") {
       alert("Please select the start time.");
     } else {
       selectedTime.setMinutes(selectedTime.getMinutes() + parseInt(meetingLength, 10), 0);
       $('#etime').timepicker('setTime', selectedTime);
     }
   }

   $('#stime').timepicker({
     'timeFormat': 'h:i a',
     'minTime': '8:00 AM',
     'maxTime': '5:00 PM',
     'step': 30
   }).on(function() {
     setEndTime();
   });

   $('#etime').timepicker({
     'timeFormat': 'h:i a',
     'minTime': '8:00 AM',
     'maxTime': '5:00 PM',
     'step': 5
   });

   $('#meeting').bind('change', function() {
     setEndTime();
   });
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.9/jquery.timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.9/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

<tr>
  <th>Start Time:</th>
  <td>
    <input type="text" id="stime" name="stime" class="time" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Length of meeting:</th>
  <td>
    <select name="meeting" id="meeting">
      <option value="">--Select length--</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>End Time:</th>
  <td>
    <input type="text" id="etime" name="etime" class="time">
  </td>
</tr>
```

I'm not sure where my code should be modified to give me end times based on selected interval. If see where is my code breaking please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Jsfiddle could be useful.

Comment: Here is one that I found but does not work for me, contain refresh option that could not be used with my plugin and I tried many others but always gave me an error. http://jsfiddle.net/20m6b7qz/5/

Answer (score 2):

Change the `step` property of #etime to be a function (so dynamic value) using the interval:

```
$('#etime').timepicker({
  'timeFormat': 'h:i a',
  'minTime': '8:00 AM',
  'maxTime': '5:00 PM',
  'step': function(i) {
            return $('#meeting').val() || 5;
          }
});
```

**Runnable example**

```js
$(function() {
  for (var i = 5; i <= 60; i += 5) {
    $('#meeting').append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '   min' + '</option>');
  }

  function setEndTime() {
    var meetingLength = parseInt($('#meeting').find('option:selected').val() || 0);
    var selectedTime = $('#stime').timepicker('getTime');
    if (selectedTime == null || selectedTime == "") {
      alert("Please select the start time.");
    } else {
      selectedTime.setMinutes(selectedTime.getMinutes() + parseInt(meetingLength, 10), 0);
      $('#etime').timepicker('setTime', selectedTime);
    }
  }

  $('#stime').timepicker({
    'timeFormat': 'h:i a',
    'minTime': '8:00 AM',
    'maxTime': '5:00 PM',
    'step': 30
  }).on(function() {
    setEndTime();
  });

  $('#etime').timepicker({
    'timeFormat': 'h:i a',
    'minTime': '8:00 AM',
    'maxTime': '5:00 PM',
    'step': 5
  });

  $('#meeting').bind('change', function() {
    $('#etime').timepicker('remove');
    $('#etime').timepicker({
      'timeFormat': 'h:i a',
      'minTime': '8:00 AM',
      'maxTime': '5:00 PM',
      'step': $('#meeting').val()
    });
    setEndTime();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.9/jquery.timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.9/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

<tr>
  <th>Start Time:</th>
  <td>
    <input type="text" id="stime" name="stime" class="time" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Length of meeting:</th>
  <td>
    <select name="meeting" id="meeting">
      <option value="">--Select length--</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>End Time:</th>
  <td>
    <input type="text" id="etime" name="etime" class="time">
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Edit**

Since the picker doesn't refresh when the interval changes, there is a dirty trick to force the refresh, completely remove the picker and recreate it (I edited the above snippet):

```
$('#etime').timepicker({
  'timeFormat': 'h:i a',
  'minTime': '8:00 AM',
  'maxTime': '5:00 PM',
  'step': 5
});

$('#meeting').bind('change', function() {
  $('#etime').timepicker('remove');
  $('#etime').timepicker({
    'timeFormat': 'h:i a',
    'minTime': '8:00 AM',
    'maxTime': '5:00 PM',
    'step': $('#meeting').val()
  });
  setEndTime();
});
```

Comment: Now end time change after I pick interval and that works fine, but if I change interval second time, only first value will change all other values are still the same as I picked first time. How that problem can be fixed?

Comment: @user3023588 You have to force the timepicker to refresh/redraw, I don't know how to do that. I edited my answer to add a default step value of 5.

Comment: I tried to use refresh but that gave me an Error: Method refresh does not exist on jQuery.timepicker. So I do not how to fix this. Thank you for help with this.

Comment: @user3023588 I found a way but it's kinda dirty: remove the picker, recreate it. Check the edit on my answer.

Comment: So I had some time to test this and found few things that does not work right. So if you pick some random start time let say 9:00 am and then pick interval 35min, end time will show up as value 9:35am but then if you click on drop down that value does not exist. Drop down starts at 8:00am and interval is added on that value. Only in few cases works fine, I think for 60min gives correct values but for other does not work right. Thanks for help but I think I will have to dig more to find better solution.

Comment: @user3023588 You can make minTime of #etime dynamic too `'minTime': $('#stime').val()`. You could move the reset code of #etime (remove, recreate) at the beginning of the `setEndTime()` function so when the start date or the interval is changed, the end time list is recreated as it should. You forgot `'change'` here `$('#stime').timepicker().on('change', function() { });`